# angular rxjs groupby mergemap return single value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have following code which group and count items by type. i want to make a change and make `groupBy` `return` single object.

for example after mergeMap complete its operation, i want to attach another operator which will analyze following result and return single value 'true' or 'false' for whole result set.

```
{ type: 'foo', total: 1 }
{ type: 'bar', total: 2 }

const list = [{ type: 'foo' }, { type: 'bar' }, { type: 'bar' }];

Observable.from( list ).groupBy( x => x.type )
  .mergeMap( list$ => { // each emission is a stream

    /* A stream of "aggregated" data. */
    const count$ = list$.count();

    /* Format the result. */
    return count$.map( count => ({ type: list$.key, count }));
  }).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

This emits:

```
{ type: 'foo', total: 1 }
{ type: 'bar', total: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use the reduce() method (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/reduce.md)

"Applies an accumulator function over an observable sequence, **returning the result of the aggregation as a single element** in the result sequence"